# How to make a command that disconnects a user from a voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

How can i make a command that disconnects a user from a voice channel. I use discord.py. I want a command that disconnects a user not to move a user.

Comment: Just take a look at the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) as they will tell you everything you need to know and you even learn new things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `move_to` and as channel pass `None`.

Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.move_to(None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I got my answer

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, i am not too sure if this is the answer you are looking for specifically, but this way you can disconnect a specific user.

```
async def kick(ctx: commands.Context, user: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} was kicked from {user.voice.channel.mention}')
    await user.move_to(None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.